# How do cryptocurrency exchange services generate disposable / sub-addresses?

Tags: sub-address, integrated-address, api, p2p-exchange

I am developing my cryptocurrency exchange service.
The first problem - how to distinguish clients from each other?
It seems to me that other services have solved this problem by generating something like a one-time address for each client - and then this problem is 100% solved.
I found a theoretical article about generating disposable addresses for monero.
But what about other cryptocurrencies? Tell me please where I can read about it?
At least for the top 10 cryptocurrencies.
Interested in automatic generation, or api integration with some services. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Monero, service providers generally use the [Monero Wallet RPC (monero-wallet-rpc)](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html). To create a subaddress, see: [create_address](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#create_address).

> But what about other cryptocurrencies?

Refer to the *"other cryptocurrencies"* documentation / StackExchanges.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!